# How to parse parts of a string and insert them into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in my database that stores data like so:

```
 Description - (Width 1 Height 1)
```

I need to parse this string and insert the Width and Height into 2 new columns.

I currently have this query:

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN Description LIKE '%Width %' THEN SUBSTRING(Description, CHARINDEX('Width ', Description) + 6, 1)
      END AS Width,
      CASE
        WHEN Description LIKE '%Height %' THEN SUBSTRING(Description, CHARINDEX('Height ', Description) + 7, 1)
      END AS Height
FROM table
```

It works great with this query, but if I have an entry like this, it only grabs the first digit:

```
Description - (Width 25 Height 10)
```

I know this is because I am using '1' as the length of my SUBSTRING, but I am not sure how I can make this work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not make parsing strings easy.

```
SELECT LEFT(v.wstr, CHARINDEX(' ', v.wstr + ' ') - 1) as width,
       LEFT(v.hstr, CHARINDEX(' ', v.hstr + ' ') - 1) as width,      
FROM table OUTER APPLY
     (VALUES (STUFF(Description, 1, CHARINDEX('Width ', Description + 'Width ') + 6, ''), 
              STUFF(Description, 1, CHARINDEX('Height ', Description + 'Height ') + 7, ''),
             )
     ) v(wstr, hstr);
```

Notes:

- Unlike your version, this returns an empty string when the values are not present, rather than `NULL` (it is easy to add the `CASE` back in).
- Like your version, this assumes that the pattern ends with a space.
- Like your version, this assumes that "Width" and "Height" do not appear in the description.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL 2016, you can use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) and parse the individual pieces.

If not, it's a bit more difficult:

```
declare @testString varchar(50) = '(Width 25 Height 10)',
        @widthStart int,
        @widthEnd int,
        @heightStart int,
        @heightEnd int

select  @widthStart = CHARINDEX('Width ', @testString),
        @heightStart = CHARINDEX('Height ', @testString)

select  @widthEnd = @widthStart + LEN('Width '),
        @heightEnd = @heightStart + LEN('Height ')

select  Width = SUBSTRING(@testString, @widthEnd, @heightStart - @widthEnd),
        Height = SUBSTRING(@testString, @heightEnd, LEN(@testString) - @heightEnd)
```

Here I've made a bunch of different variables to show how `SUBSTRING` is working. Basically, get the index after width, and go until you hit the next space - do the same for height, except we're looking at `LEN(@testString)` to end it.

This will correctly return `25`, `10` for Width and Height. This works as long as you can guarantee the format the string will be in - it will not work if this format changes.

Ideally, these values would be stored in separate columns in the database - then you don't need to worry about SQL splitting strings.

EDIT:

As a side note, you'll (likely) end up wanting to `LTRIM(RTRIM(Width))` and `Height` to remove any spaces that end up in the resulting substring.

Answer (score 0):

This query could run well for any length of height, width,  except for case ( Height xxxxx - Width xxxxx)

```
DECLARE @Description AS TABLE (Description varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @Description
VALUES( 'Width 252 Height 1011'), ('Width 2 Height 22'),('Width 2144'), ('Height 2133')

SELECT CHARINDEX('Width', 'Width 25 Height 10')
;WITH temps AS
(
    SELECT   
        CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX('Height', d.Description) > 1 THEN CHARINDEX('Height', d.Description)
            ELSE 1
        END AS IndexPosition,
        d.Description
    FROM @Description d
)
SELECT 
t.Description,
CASE 
    WHEN t.IndexPosition = 1 AND t.Description LIKE '%Width%' THEN RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(t.Description,'Width','' ))) 
    WHEN t.IndexPosition = 1 AND t.Description LIKE '%Height%' THEN NULL
    ELSE RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(t.Description, 0, t.IndexPosition -1),'Width','' ))) 
END AS Width,
CASE 
    WHEN t.IndexPosition = 1 AND t.Description LIKE '%Height%' THEN RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(t.Description,'Height','' ))) 
    WHEN t.IndexPosition = 1 AND t.Description LIKE '%Width%' THEN NULL
    ELSE RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(t.Description, t.IndexPosition, LEN(t.Description)),'Height','' ))) 
END AS Height
FROM temps t
```